# How to find limits of selection based on (using) selected random numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, statistics, probability-theory

I have a set (selection) of randomly generated numbers. For example:

> 13 14 9 10 14 10 10 11 16 9 9 12 10 10 15 16 12 10 13 12 11 13 14 17 12 11 9 15 13 9 16 14 12 10 10 11 11 14 11 15 13 12 8 16 14 10 12 14 12 12 14 9 10 15 8 12 15 13 14 18 12 7 11 11 15 14 17 9 9 10 15 11 13 12 18 14 10 14 10 15 15 13 7 15 12 11 12 14 10 9 12 12 5 8 9 13 16 14 14 13

I mean it looks like that those numbers were not generated within the scope like from -100 to 10000. The right answer is the limits were from 5 to 20. 
How to define that bounds (the lowest limit and the highest limit) of selection?
I feel I have to use `Expected value` or `Variance` somehow, but have no idea how.

One more example:

> 35 16 19 21 20 34 24 27 24 24 24 16 33 23 35 23 19 20 19 30 29 25 21 34 14 20 34 16 24 22 27 12 21 20 25 17 21 21 32 21 17 19 20 30 22 21 9 14 24 18 23 24 26 20 13 22 32 21 20 29 21 25 24 18 25 27 22 28 26 13 23 17 28 26 26 30 21 18 23 29 28 28 26 14 17 28 25 19 22 16 25 33 22 20 24 27 32 22 21 27

Answer: All those numbers were generated from the scope 5 - 40

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Are you trying to find the bounds of the generation process by looking at the randomly generated numbers?

Comment: it seems the limits are from 5 to 18

Comment: Are you asking 'Assuming I know that theses integers were generated by `randomInt(lowerBound, upperBound)`, how do I determine what `lowerBound` and `upperBound` were?'?

Comment: @bradimus, yes. Normally the task is like:"Students, please generate 40 numbers using scope (limits) 3 - 24" And you will not get selection like " 3, 3, 3, 4 , 24, etc." most probable values would be around 13 and 14. My task here is oppsite. I have a set of generated numbers and have to find the scope values (limits)...3-24 in this case.

Comment: If you make some assumptions on how the values were generated, such as a Uniform Distribution with the number of  samples is large compared to the range of the distribution, you can get reliable estimates for what true upper and lower bounds are. With those two assumptions, the bounds on your sample are likely to be the bounds on the distribution.

Comment: You'd be better of asking this question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ There are a lot of approaches (MLE, Bayesian and [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic))

Comment: If you are especially referring to a discrete uniform distribution, your problem also has a close connection to the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)

Answer (score 1):

You could load your sequence of numbers into a `SortedSet`, e.g. `TreeSet`, and then take advantage of the min and max functions it has:

```
TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<>();
// add your data using ts.add()
System.out.println("lower bound is " + ts.first());
System.out.println("upper bound is " + ts.last());
```

Comment: I don't think that is what he is asking. I believe he's looking for a way to infer the limits used to generate the random numbers, not the bounds of what was generated.

Comment: @bradimus Let's see what the OP says.  In any case, I think he will have to touch each element in his set at least once.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for MIN and MAX. By the way I did it using `Collections.max(b)` the task is to find bounds. I have added one more examples into the question. You can see that all elements were generated in the scope 5-40, though MIN=9 and MAX=35

Comment: What statistical range are you trying to compute?

Comment: @SergeyLotvin No, we cannot see that. In fact, if the distribution used is uniform (which is what you seem to use), it is more probable that the bounds are the extrema than anything else.

Comment: @Nelxiost Or at least the bounds will tend toward the extrema as the number of points generated becomes arbitrarily large.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, I can't think of any generated distribution for which you would not expect the bounds to be the extrema, even with a small number of points. Unless the distribution isn't uniform.

Comment: @Nelxiost, do you mean that there is no Math formula that could (with some extent of probability) compute the scope of selection?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is impossible. You cannot find the bounds used to generate a uniformly distributed series of numbers.

A simple way to prove that is to compute the probability of generating a given series of numbers using various bounds.

Let `min` be the minimum number found in the series, `max`, the maximum, and `len`, the length of the series. We want to find `low` and `up`, respectively the lower bound and upper bound used to generate the series. Let `p(l, u)` be the probability of generating the series with a lower bound equal to `l` and an upper bound equal to `u`.

For any `l > min`, `p(l, u) = 0`. Similarly, for any `u < max`, `p(l, u) = 0`.

For `l <= min` and `u >= max`, `p(l, u) = (1/(u-l))^len`, because each number is generated with a probability of `1/(u-l)`. Now, we want to maximize `p`, which means we want to find `low` and `up` such that, for any `l` and `u`, `p(low, up) >= p(l, u)`.

This is easy : if `f(x) = (1/x)^y`, with `x > 0` and `y > 1`, then the maximum of `f` is achieved for the smallest `x` possible.

In our problem, `x = up-low`, so we want to minimize `up-low`, which is the same as minimizing `up` and maximizing `low`.

This leads to the solution : `up = max` and `low = min`.

If the actual bounds used are not the extrema found, then guessing the true bounds would be improbable.